# Как удалить спецсимволы в конце и начале строки? Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Есть строка

```
</n></t>http://text.ru</n></t>
```

Как в Котлине удалить все спецсимволы только в начале и конце строки?

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, Вам нужно написать подобный алгоритм:

```
String hyperText = "</n></t>http://text.ru</n></t>";
String[] array = hyperText.split(">");              // "</n", "</t", "http://text.ru</n", "</t"
String clearString = "";
for(String part : array){
    if(part.charAt(0) != '<'){                      // "http://text.ru</n"
        String[] subArray = part.split(">");        // "http://text.ru", "/n"
        clearString += subArray[0];                 // "http://text.ru"
    }
}
```

Возможно, он даже будет прваильно работать для чередования строк и тэгов =)